# How to round in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

How do you round 0.2356 to 0.23 in Google BigQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `ROUND` returns `float`, hence it has two parameters and in the 2nd parameter you are able to define the decimals you want returned. Others `CEIL`, `FLOOR` return `integer`, hence no second parameter, but you can mimic the decimals by using math.

```
select floor(0.2356*100)/100
```

[Google BigQuery Documentation -> Functions and Operators -> Mathematical Function -> ROUND](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#round)

Comment: One point of clarification for this answer, I'd recommend pointing out that the OP is looking to round **down** to the nearest **0.01** and that this is the reason for providing [FLOOR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#floor) instead of [ROUND](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#round) in the sample code as `ROUND(0.2356 * 100) / 100` would yield **0.24**.