# How can I fix the precision of float value problem by TRUNC or ROUND in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

When I run the sql code below at bigquery,

```
SELECT ROUND( 43.097410399271645, 6)
```

I expected to get 43.097410 but I got the result below,

```
43.097409999999996
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round in bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572327/how-to-round-in-bigquery)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I can use that method to be round the values. 
However, I want to also know the reason why this issue happens. Is it a bug in Google Big query?

Comment: More like a bug. If you round of the 0 and the next digit is 4 or below then it produces the scenario above but if the next digit to 0 is 5 or higher then it works fine. You may file the issue here, then look for the BQ issue --> https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: That's not a bug and not specific to BigQuery. That is an unavoidable problem when representing real numbers using binary storage. Hence many weird but not very significant errors when translating results back to real numbers. And also the reason you should never do *exact* comparisons on reals but only comparisons to a certain degree of precision.